# Decrease Memory Usage Loading Bitmap (Win2D)

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

I'm writing a program that uses Win2D to load an image file and display it on the screen. However, the image file itself is about 5 Mb in size, but when I load it using CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync, the process memory jumps up to over 600MB in memory and then settles down to around 300MB. Is there any way to reduce the process memory without having to resize the image manually in an image editor? I've seen code for resizing other types of bitmaps and I was wondering if that's also possible in Win2D.

Regards,
Alex

Update (1/27/2020)

Realized that bitmaps are uncompressed image files, so the only avalible options are either to reduce the image size somehow, or use a different file format. Decided to use the later because I'm working with PDF files. They can be converted into SVG files using Inkscape. Also, SVG files conveniently happen to be supported by Win2D.

Comment: What are the image specifications? Besides size, i.e. dimensions, bbp, etc.

Comment: It's an A1 jpg at 300dpi, so that means 42.0 cm x 59.3 cm, or 9933 pixels x 7017 pixels. I don't know how many bits per pixel it is though.

Comment: I tested the CanvasBitmap.LoadAsync method by using the 300dpi, 5 MB jpg, but the memory increased from 62MB to 89MB instead of 600MB. Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test? And if you set your image file size explicitly and then load it, will the memory decrease?

Comment: Well, it kind of makes sense; if the jpeg is decompressed in memory, you'll endup with a 70Mpixel (10k x 7k) l, lets say 4 bytes each = 280 MB.

Comment: @Stefan Yes, I only just learned bitmaps are uncompressed images. I've resorted to converting the image to a SVG file which cuts the size by a third.